# Custom-built NAND SR latch not resetting

Tags: logisim

I'm trying to build SR latch in Logisim using NAND gates, but I seem to be unable to get the latch to truly reset. I can set S to 0 and R to 1, but once I set it back to 0, Q goes back to being 1. How do I get Q to be 0 when S is 0 and R is 0?

[image: screenshot of Logisim circuit]

Comment: NAND flip flops are behaving the opposite way to the NOR FFs. `S=1` will set `Q=0`. Unless you swap `Q` and `Q'`...

Comment: What you're describing is normal behavior for NAND SR latches. You're probably expecting NOR SR latch results (which have the opposite input polarity).

Answer (score 3):

The inputs to a NAND RS latch are **active low**, meaning that they perform the desired function when brought to a logic 0. If you force your R input to 0 while S=1 you will see that Q2' goes high and Q2 goes low. If R=1 and you force S to 0 then Q2' goes low and Q2 goes high.

If both R=1 and S=1 then the latch is in its hold state, and it maintains whatever value it previously had.

Setting R=0 and S=0 simultaneously is an illegal input state. In this state both Q2 and Q2' will be high. The big problem is that if you transition from the illegal state (R=0, S=0) directly to the hold state (R=1, S=1) then the state of the latch is indeterminate, and in the real world you could have metastability.